# jQuery : how to store textbox values in array for each row (tr wise)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have created a table where each `td` has textboxes, now have to store each texbox values in an Array by each row wise ie(for each tr)

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zQNUW/5/)

SO desired Output like

```
  array[0]->ABC1,S/W developer1,abc1,22z,123 // 1st row values
  array[1]->PQR2,S/W developer2,abc2,22z,123 // 2nd row values
```

Comment: In first place, no one will guess what the _themeoptions_ database is. Second, if you are using a database, why do you need the array at all if all you want to do is populate a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textbox values in array for each row (tr wise)

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/zQNUW/10/

```
$("#update").click(function () {
    x = [];
    $('table tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
        y = '';
        $(this).find('td input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            y += $(this).val() + ' ';
        });
        if (y != '') {
            x.push($.trim(y))
        }
    });
    alert(x);
    console.log(x);
});
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/zQNUW/7/

```
$("#update").click(function () {
    x = [];
    $('table tr td input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        x.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(x);
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ... I want output like ..`array[0]->{data of 1st row}            array[1]->{data of 2nd row}` etc...